# Чи можна віднести іменник ТРУП до граматичної групи аналогічних лексем мрець, покійник?

Tags: іменники

Традиційно ще зі школи ми знаємо, що **труп**-неістота [Українська без помилок. Говоримо і пишемо правильно...](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=fOwVCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT199&lpg=PT199&dq=%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA+-%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=DBrK1PftBO&sig=aG4t1H1FaPZA560msqN1kr6Oh2s&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCkqHH_qrbAhVL2ywKHT73CvUQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20-%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0&f=false) . однак натрапила на статтю [Мороз Т. Ю. Специфіка вираження значень істоти/неістоти в аспекті виявів семантико-граматичної асиметрії](http://www.irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/irbis_nbuv/cgiirbis_64.exe?I21DBN=LINK&P21DBN=UJRN&Z21ID=&S21REF=10&S21CNR=20&S21STN=1&S21FMT=ASP_meta&C21COM=S&2_S21P03=FILA=&2_S21STR=Nvchnugf_2014_692-693_32), де автор зазначає, що

> ...у контекстах, де іменник **труп**  уживається самостійно, він може цілком набувати формальних ознак істотового. Як засвідчує вибірка, таких контекстів чимало, наприклад:
>   Московські драгуни не спішилися збирати своїх  поранених і **трупів**; То нащо двигати **трупа**?
>
> У цілому слід зазначити, що цей іменник, перебуваючи в ряду подібних йому за семантикою лексем  *покійник, мрець, небіжчик* поступово граматично уніфікується, вирівнюється[...] З огляду на ці міркування бачиться виправданим зарахування аналізованого іменника до граматичної групи аналогічних **лексем мрець, покійник**.

Чи є можливим, що з часом в традиційному мовознавстві  слово **ТРУП** відноситиметься до граматичної групи аналогічних лексем **мрець, покійник** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Труп** не має шансів стати в ряд зі словами **мрець**, **небіжчик**, **покійник** на основі спільної категорії істоти. На це є наступні міркування:

1. З огляду на семантику: труп є лиш частиною померлої людини, нарівні з її біографічною особою, памяттю про неї, міфологічними душею, аурою тощо.

Людина як особа є конгломератом понять тіла, розуму, душі, а [істота](http://sum.in.ua/s/istota) - сукупність усіх фізичних та душевних властивостей людини, живий організм тощо.

Персоніфікувати неактивну тілесну частину людини неправильно. Скажімо, не можна вважати істотою ампутовану руку чи відрізане волосся. Труп є предметною складовою людини, хай навіть і більш-менш цілістною.

2. З огляду на граматику нема підстав вважати цілком поширений процес метафоризації значення слова чимось більшим, як-от міграцією лексеми з однієї категорії в іншу. Така думка досить поверхнева. Адже граматичні категорії особи, числа, істоти/неістоти гнучкі, у різних контекстах вони можуть змінюватися в межах однієї лексеми.

Інші думки:

3. вживання лексеми із закінченням родового відмінка не покажчик істоти, а [діалектна норма](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=18724), тому контекст "нащо двигати трупа" - це ілюстрація не персональності, а діалектного вжитку.
4. у криміналістиці, яка практично підходить до поняття **труп**, надання лексемі категорії істоти може викликати розрив шаблону, коли, скажімо, тіло втрачає фізичні ознаки особи (розчленування, гниття, під час ексгумації та ін.).

Звісно, граматична категорія істоти/неістоти лише формально і частково збігається зі звичним уявленням про живе/неживе, особу/неособу, але набуття лексемою унормованих відмінкових закінчень, як у істоти призведе до зміни у сприйнятті значення слова **труп**. А основне значення його змінитися не може - це тіло людини **безвідносно до її особистості**. На відміну від слів небіжчик чи покійник - евфемізмів, труп - пряма вказівка на мертве тіло.

Прийнятними варіантами, коли можна надати слову труп категорію істоти є наступні приклади (на додачу до прикладів із цитати з роботи Т.Мороз):

А. **живий труп** - переносне значення, про живу людину, що погано виглядає, особу, однозначно це істота;

Б. **ходячий труп, зомбі** - персонаж, істота.

Comment: «Вживання лексеми із закінченням родового відмінка не покажчик істоти, а діалектна норма» — цілком згоден, теж хотів це сказати ([«Вони потренуються та „**Кубка** \[Кубок\] СРСР“ нам виграють!» (Остап Вишня)](http://sum.in.ua/s/potrenuvatysja)).